# Add a HTTP link to SSL HTTPS page without causing Mixed-Content "Not Secure" error

Tags: javascript, html

**How can I add un-secured HTTP links on this page without causing the error "Not Secure."?**

- I have a secured web page with SSL HTTPS.
- This web page is a dashboard with 100+ buttons which all contain links of external websites.
- Unfortunately, not all of these websites support HTTPS ...common its 2020!

Is there any way to resolve this issue while maintaining the site lock?

**Attempt #1**

```
<link rel="ampHtml" href="http://example.com/">
```

**Attempt #2**

> I used TinyURL to convert my HTTP links into short URLs which have
>   HTTPS. ...this works for most of the links (which is great!)
>
> The remaining links when clicked have additional Javascript which is
>   adding URL querystrings to the end of the URLs. These strings apply on
>   the TinyURL successfully, but does not on the final destination URL.

**The only other solutions I can think of (if even possible) is ...**

- JavaScript to convert specific links onClick to HTTP before opening a new tab and loading the website.
- JavaScript to delay the load of the HTTP link.

Comment: This is like you'd take your safety belt off just before crash.

Comment: I totally agree! ...if these HTTP website were public websites, however thats not the case. 

The main site (Dashboard)  with HTTPS is a public website, where as the 100+ links contained inside are HTTP. 

These HTTP sites are an internal website within an intranet protected by a VPN and not visible on the internet. 

...an easy solution would be to make the Dashboard website HTTP, and host it internally in the intranet, but I cant.

Comment: Then, just ignore the warning, as its safe for you as per your evaluation. That warning will help you to remind yourself that this site is not safe outside the intranet.

Comment: I have been ignoring the message for over a year. This dashboard is used daily and on average has 500 clicks/day/user. Thats 500 warnings where users have to click "Advanced" button on the "Your connection is not private" page. Resulting in 33 minutes/user wasted in extra clicks, and 2x page loads. Although your solution works, I am hoping there might be better solution to eliminate this error. 

Although the HTTPS Dashboard website is "technically" public, its also protected by User/Pass at a directory level, and is 99% of the time used inside the intranet environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a redirect page. The most basic way is making a redirection page with JavaScript.

```
if (window.location.search.includes("?url=")) {
  var url = window.location.search.replace("?url=", "");
  window.location.replace(url);
}
```

Basically, what's happening is that it redirects from a secure page to a non-secure page without causing a 'Mixed Content' error. It gets the `url` parameter from `window.location.search` and then it redirects to that.